# Relation between different versions of Bar-Natan homology

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, khovanov-homology

In Bar-Natan's paper: **[Khovanov’s homology for tangles and cobordisms](https://dx.doi.org/10.2140/gt.2005.9.1443)**, he defined a deformation of Khovanov homology. Namely, for any $m\geq 0$, Bar-Natan's homology $BN^{m}(K)$ is obtained by tensoring the original Khovanov complex with a ring $F_{2}[U]/U^{m}$ and then adding an extra term in the Khovanov differential.

Question: Are there relations between the $BN^{m}(K)$ for different $m$? In particular, is it true that by setting $U^{m}=0$ in $BN^{\infty}(K)$, one obtains $BN^{m}(K)$? (Somehow I do not see why this is true from pure algebraic reasoning.)